# What are the roles of min_sample_split and min_sample_leaf in RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on fitting a [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and came across two parameters: `min_sample_split` and `min_sample_leaf`.

Do I need to set both `min_sample_split` and `min_sample_leaf`?

I think I just need one of them since one is effectively half of the other. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: You might be pleased to know that `min_samples_leaf` is being [deprecated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11280).

Comment: @Stev: thanks for clarification. going through the link you suggested, I understand that a split can happen with unequal number of leaf nodes in each resulting node the size of which is basically controlled through min_sample_leaf size. Can you please throw some light on the reasoning behind this? If I understand it correctly it is probably because of decisioning approach of underlying algorithm.

Comment: The `criterion` parameter (or impurity function) is evaluated for all candidate splits. It might be the case that the best split (the one that has the largest decrease in impurity) results in only 1 sample being in 1 leaf and the rest of the samples being in the other. You might not want this to occur, maybe to avoid overfitting, so you might want to terminate to tree at this point by setting `min_samples_leaf`. However, it looks like `min_samples_leaf` in SKLearn doesn't terminate the tree and in fact looks at the next best split instead.

Answer (score 3):

So basically `min_sample_split` is the minimum no. of sample required for a split. For instance, if `min_sample_split = 6` and there are 4 samples in the node, then the split will not happen (regardless  of entropy).

`min_sample_leaf` on the other hand is basically the minimum no. of sample required to be a leaf node.  For example, if a node contains 5 samples, it can be split into two leaf nodes of size 2 and 3 respectively. Now suppose you have `min_sample_leaf = 3`, then the split will not occur, because the minimum leaf size if 3, and you can't have a new node with only 2 samples.

You can take a look at [this](https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/what-does-min-samples-split-means-in-decision-tree/6233/2) and [this](https://medium.com/@mohtedibf/indepth-parameter-tuning-for-decision-tree-6753118a03c3) for further reading.

**Update** : the difference in behaviour of RandomForest and GradientBoostClassifier is attributed largely to the way how they train themselves(gradient boosting is an ensemble of sequential classifiers), you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/mlreview/gradient-boosting-from-scratch-1e317ae4587d) to understand the internal working of gradient boosting

Comment: @kashif: thanks for clarification. So min_sample_split and min_sample_leaf are complementary to each other. I have done a bit of testing on RandomForestClassifier and found that keeping min_sample_leaf size below 50% of min_sample_split does not impact the results. However, probably for some reason (I don't know) the same is not true for GradientBoostingClassifier where varying min_sample_leaf size even when it is below 50% of min_sample_split affects the results.